# Why did Bella become more powerful when she became a vampire?

Tags: character, the-twilight-saga

In *The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn Part 2*, why did Bella become more powerful when she became a vampire? Even Edward, Rosalie and Jasper were humans who later became vampires and no doubt they all are powerful but Bella is much more powerful than them. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bella, as a human being has an extraordinary shield power which makes her immune to Edward & Jane's mind power.

It is mentioned in the movie, I think by Alice, that a vampire's powers are an enhanced version of the qualities they had as a human. So as a Vampire, Bella's powers of shield are enhanced & she can project that power outward to others minds as well.

If however you are asking about her strength as a vampire overpowering Edward, that strength boost is temporary for a new born Vampire as seen in the movie Eclipse. I don't remember the exact reason but something to do with hormonal changes as a new born vampire.

Answer (score 0):

because in first part James bite Bella and also Edward that's why she has the power of both or maybe because of her psychic ability

Comment: Welcome to the site! We're looking for answers that are reasonably well justified by the source material and reasonably authoritative. Obviously, one can never state something with absolute certainty about a fictional world, but we are looking for something better than "maybe". For example, why in the _Twilight_ universe would being bitten by two vampires make her more powerful? (Actually, are you saying that James bit Bella and Edward, or that James and Edward both bit Bella?)